# How to implement an entity bound odata action in olingo v4.3

Tags: java, odata, olingo

Similar to this post, I'm trying to implement an action bound to an entity

[How to create a bounded action in Olingo V4 (java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38736115/how-to-create-a-bounded-action-in-olingo-v4-java)

but I get a 500 with no error logged when I GET the metadata document.

In the answer to the above linked question, there is no mention of the `getActionImport()` implementation that is described in the olingo tutorial, and I wonder if this needs to be modified for an entity-bound action?

How can I get olingo to log the error that is causing the 500?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting the debug output is actually quite easy:

```
handler.register(new DefaultDebugSupport());
```

where handler is a `ODataHttpHandler`

Armed with this, and after examination of the olingo-server-core code, I discovered:

1. You don't need an ActionImport at all for bound actions.
2. The action name in the URL needs to be qualified with the namespace, as https://issues.oasis-open.org/browse/ODATA-812 has not been implemented.
3. When I built the client URL using `org.apache.olingo.client.api.uri.URIBuilder`, it wrapped the entity ID in single quotes, and then olingo server threw an exception, so I reverted to using a `StringBuilder`